# "This is joint work with ..." vs "this is a joint work with ..."

Tags: grammar

I saw both sentences "This is joint work with ..." and "this is a joint work with ..." in many math talks abstracts. I wonder if they are both correct. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use "work" as both a countable and an uncountable noun, so the answer is yes. The explanation and proper grammatical terms I'll gladly leave to the professionals.

Answer (score 3):

They are **both correct**, but **mean slightly different things**.

From Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:

> noun
>   JOB/TASK
>   1. **uncountable** the job that a person does especially in order to earn money
>   Syn: ↑employment
>   out of work (= without a job)
>   (BrE) in work (= have a job)
>   started work
>   return to work
>   line of work (= what type of work do you do)
>   before/after work (= in the morning/evening each day)
>   full-time/part-time/unpaid/voluntary work
>   2. **uncountable** the duties that you have and the activities that you do as part of your job
>   see also ↑piecework, ↑social work
>   3. **uncountable** tasks that need to be done
>   work to be done
>   hard work
>   see also ↑homework, ↑schoolwork
>   4. **uncountable** materials needed or used for doing work, especially books, papers, etc
>   (= for example, files and documents)
>   see also ↑paperwork
>   ...
>   EFFORT
>   6. **uncountable** the use of physical strength or mental power in order to do or make sth
>   hard work
>   started work on
>   life's work
>   set them to work
>   PRODUCT OF WORK
>   7. **uncountable** a thing or things that are produced as a result of work
>   all your own work (= did you do it without help from others)
>   piece of work

As you can see, the noun is uncountable in most contexts, but it could also be countable if it means:

> BOOK/MUSIC/ART
>   9. **countable** a book, piece of music, painting, etc
>   collected/complete works
>   works of fiction/literature

So, by "*a joint work*", the authors are referring to the *research paper itself*, and you *can't really label it grammatically incorrect*, though it still sounds a bit off.

I'd almost always go with just "*joint work*", as in *collaborative research effort/task/project*.